# Android - App in Power Saving Mode fails to connect to the internet while not in foreground

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, androidhttpclient, httpsurlconnection

I have an app which I wake up using GCM notification and make it connect to the server via an https connection.

I noticed on recent android OS that when my app enters power saving mode ("apps that have not been used for more than 3 days have been set to save power") and I send a GCM notification, it wakes up and fails to connect to server (Connection Refused).

It only gains internet access if it is running in the foreground.

Any idea how to disallow my app from entering power saving mode? I need to be able to reach the device at any point. Specially that my app is  DEVICE ADMIN app.

Comment: the user has to do this, you cannot do it in app